# grep with alphabet

Tags: grep

I want to look for all the lines in my file `file.txt` which contains the pattern `phone/number/` followed by a lowercase alphabet (a-z). I know that for just `phone/number/`, I can use

```
grep "phone/number/" file.txt
```

But what about the alphabet following it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
grep 'phone/number/[a-z]' file.txt
```